# Cómo pasar parametros del análisis Quicksight a un control que tiene una lista?

Tags: aws, data, desarrollo

En AWS Quicksight tengo un análisis con dos dataset: dataset 1 es utilizado para los graficos y dataset2 es utilizado para los controles.
En el análisis tengo dos parámetros: tenant y userId que toman valores variables dependiendo de lo que se pase en la url embebida.
Necesito que la lista que tengo en los controles sea filtrada por esos parámetros.
No puedo pasar el parámetro al dataset2 xq si lo hago se me queda con los valores prestablecidos y no me hace dinámico el dataset